# Null Pointer Exception While doing MergeSort Method

Tags: java, merge, mergesort

I want to create a class and use it as a data type to create a MergeSort program using array. I created to program but it's giving me null pointer exception and I don't know why.

Employee Class

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>
{
private String firstname;
private int idNumber;
private String lastname;


  Employee(String fname, String lname, int id)
{  
  firstname = fname;
  idNumber = id;
  lastname = lname;

}


public void setFirstName(String fname)
    {firstname = fname;}
public String getFirstName()
    {return firstname;}

public void setidNumber(int id)
     {idNumber = id;}
public int getidNumber()
    {return idNumber;}

public void setLastName(String lname)
    {lastname = lname;}
public String getLastName() 
    {return lastname;}


public String toString()
{
    String str =  "\nName: " + firstname + " " + lastname
                + "\nID: "  + idNumber;

    return str;
}
public int compareTo(Employee Employee2)
    {
    int nameDiff = lastname.compareToIgnoreCase(Employee2.lastname);
    if(nameDiff != 0)

    return nameDiff;
    return -1;

       }
    }
```

Array Class

```
  class Array
    {
public Employee[] A;
public int nElems;

public Array(int max)
{
    A = new Employee[max];
    nElems = 0;
}
    public void insert(Employee value)
      {
         int j;
         for(j = 0; j < nElems; j++)
         if(A[j].equals(value))
         break;
         for(int k = nElems; k > j; k--)
         A[k] = A[k-1];
         A[j] = value;
         nElems++;
       }
public void display()
    {
    for(int j = 0; j < nElems; j++)
     System.out.print(A[j] + " ");
    System.out.println(" ");
     }

    public static void merge(Employee[] L, Employee[] R, Employee[] A)
{
    int nL = L.length;
    int nR = R.length;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    while(i < nL && j < nR)
    {
        if(L[i].compareTo(R[j]) <= 0)
        {
            A[k] = L[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            A[k] = R[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i < nL)
    {
        A[k] = L[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < nR)
    {
        A[k] = R[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
private static void _mergeSort(Employee[] A)
{
    int n = A.length;
    int i , j, mid;

    if(n < 2) return;

    mid = n/2;
    Employee[] left = new Employee[mid];
    Employee[] right = new Employee[n - mid];

    for(i = 0; i < mid; i++)
        left[i] = A[i];
    for(i = mid; i < n-mid; i++)
        right[i-mid] = A[i];
    _mergeSort(left);
    _mergeSort(right);
    merge(left, right, A);

}
public void mergeSort()
{
    _mergeSort(A);
}            
}
```

Driver Class

```
class MergeSortDriver
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  Employee s1 = new Employee("Bob","Sullivan",52);      
  Employee s2 = new Employee("Maggie", "Smith",98);
  Employee s3 = new Employee("John", "Ocasio", 85);
  Employee s4 = new Employee("Christina", "Yang", 46);

  Array arr = new Array(50);

  Employee A[] = {s1,s2,s3,s4};

  arr.insert(s1);
  arr.insert(s2);
  arr.insert(s3);
  arr.insert(s4);

  arr.display();

  arr.mergeSort();   

  arr.display();   
     }
  }
```

Error Mesg

```
   ----jGRASP exec: java MergeSortDriver
    Name: Bob Sullivan
    ID: 52 
    Name: Maggie Smith
    ID: 98 
    Name: John Ocasio
    ID: 85 
    Name: Christina Yang
    ID: 46  
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Employee.compareTo(Employee.java:37)
at Array.merge(Array.java:40)
at Array._mergeSort(Array.java:83)
at Array._mergeSort(Array.java:82)
at Array._mergeSort(Array.java:81)
at Array._mergeSort(Array.java:81)
at Array._mergeSort(Array.java:81)
at Array._mergeSort(Array.java:81)
at Array.mergeSort(Array.java:88)
at MergeSortDriver.main(Array.java:112)

    ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
    ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: Adding an `@Override` annotation to the compareTo method would be a good idea btw. Also check value of `lastname` there.

Comment: If possible go to the computer lab.  They'll be able to help you a lot better in person.  Also it hard to tell where the error is occurring because there are no line numbers in your source.

Comment: I have specific instructions about my assignment and I cant use the @override.

Comment: The error is occurring in the compareTo method. I am a beginner and I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, either only make an array of size 4 (or whatever size you are actually going to use) or split the array into arrays that have valid values (not null).

Then, in your second for loop where you split the array into the left and right side, your condition for the loop says that `i < n - mid` but since you're starting at `i = mid` you don't make the array large enough.

Change it to this and you will no longer get the exception:

```
for(i = mid; i < n; i++)
    right[i-mid] = A[i];
```

Comment: I did change it to i < n but it still gives me the error

Comment: Make sure you change the first array size to 4 and not 50. It's `<`, sorry!

Comment: Its giving an "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 in the next line right[i-mid] = A[i];

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake sorry, try using `<` with array size allocated to 4, not 50.

Comment: Name: Bob Sullivan
ID: 52 
Name: Maggie Smith
ID: 98 
Name: John Ocasio
ID: 85 
Name: Christina Yang
ID: 46  

Name: John Ocasio
ID: 85 
Name: Maggie Smith
ID: 98 
Name: Bob Sullivan
ID: 52 
Name: Christina Yang
ID: 46

Comment: Are you sure? I compiled and ran the program earlier and it sorted the 4 correctly. You should test your test cases with easy, simple stuff like "A" "A" 1 and "A" "A" 2 and see if it sorts that correctly

Comment: You're welcome, accept the answer if it helped you! Also, check to see if an array of size 6 works, I'm pretty sure it won't. Not near my computer at the moment so I'll have to update in ~15 minutes to see if size 6 works

Comment: I am going to check now.

Comment: It does work, I didn't use the `arr.insert` earlier to insert the extra two arrays. Glad I could help!

Comment: Thank you again. one more question. if I want the last name to print first so that we can actually see the list being sorted. what would i have to do? I already changed my constructor in employee to Employee(lname, fname, id) and it's still sorting the 2nd name even though my compare mehtod compares last names only.

Comment: I thought i would simply have to change the constructor parameters and the toString method but for some reason that's not working.

Comment: You can simply change the `display()` method to print the values. So in pseudo code: for each element in array: print (last name, first name, id number)

Comment: If you want to change the order instead of the display method, you can change the constructor but you must also change the values you give to the arrays initially. So you have to switch it to "Ocasio" "John" 85 instead of "John" "Ocasio" 85

Comment: Hey would you be able to help me do the same thing but with a Quick Sort method? I am having problem with it because our professor didnt show us how to do quick sort with user defined data type.

Comment: Yes, you can post a question and link it to me here or tell me when you'll post it by and I'll help you if someone hasn't done so already. :) I'll be near my computer in 20 minutes.

Comment: I haven't started writing the code yet would you be able to help if i give you the assignment?

Comment: Possibly, you should just post it as another question though as I might not be able to help you immediately.

Comment: thts the program i need help with. could u plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NullPointerException` is happening in the `Employee#compareTo` function -- make sure to read your stack trace carefully.

It's probably this line:

```
    int nameDiff = lastname.compareToIgnoreCase(Employee2.lastname);
```

If Employee2 is null, then this will fail because null doesn't have a field called lastname.

OK so what calls that?    In your merge method, you do this:

```
if(L[i].compareTo(R[j]) <= 0)
```

Are you absolutely, 100% positive that `R[j] != null`?   Your code doesn't check.  Check that.  Because if `R[j] == null` then this `NullPointerException` totally makes sense, right?

Also, no offense but this looks like Computer Science homework to me.  Make sure to post next time what you've already tried, and what your thought process is.   This can be largely taken care of by reading the stack trace really carefully.

Comment: I am new at this and I am sorry for that. But could you tell me how exactly I can fix this. because i am not understanding.

Comment: The way to fix this is first to do error checking in the merge() function.  Write a loop that checks all of the input arrays.  If any item in any input array is null, you're hosed -- the function should probably produce an error in that case.